# How to make an android app which contains three other apps?

Tags: android, apk

How to make an android app which contains three other apps?
On the main app, the icons of those three apps are displayed and by clicking on an icon, the coresponding app launches.

Like I want to display the icons of facebook, google map and gmail on the main app and by clicking on the facebook icon, facebook opens up.

Should I make a single APK file for all apps? How?

Comment: Well you could call out an intent from your activity to open the other apps. The same way that your app gets launched in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Robert for the answer... Is it possible to put all the apps in one APK file and then I call out an intent from the activity to open the other apps?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want the icons to appear in the main apps list?  If so,  what you need to do is add these lines:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

To whatever activity you want to appear in the main app drawer.

Anyway, this seems like a bad idea except in a few rare circumstances where each 'app' is distinct from the other apps, but it doesn't make sense to have one of them without having them all.

If they are essentially one app, do the world a favor and make only one icon.  If they are many apps that can exist independently of each other, make separate apk files for them  so that the user can install what he/she wants.

Answer (score 0):

I quite didnt get what u were trying to do, if you have the source codes of the other 3 apps, you could extract the activities and make the main app call the activitied (will require some more configuration though) , if you just have the apk, i think you can request the user to install all the 3 after the main app has been installed, and call them by using intents. :) Good luck on this

Comment: Thanks KSubedi for ur answer .... I just have the apk, but i dont want the user install the apps one by one. If all the apps can be contained in a single apk or all apps can be installed at the same time, it would be great

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: [bundle multiple apps in one app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283775/bundle-multiple-apps-in-one-app)