# Using YouTube Android API without Google's YouTube app?

Tags: android, youtube-api

We are developing a YouTube app (using Android YouTube APIs) for a custom Android Device. Now the problem that we do not have Google's YouTube app pre-installed on our device (which is the per-requsite for using these APIs). Following are my questions:

1. Is there any way we can use these APIs without the Google's YouTube app installed?
2. If not, is there anyway we can bundle the YouTube App apk with our app and Install the Google's app on first run of our app? Is this approach feasible?
3. What kind of permissions will be required from Google and how can we get it?

**Please Note**: We do not want to use the Native Android Video Player and we do not want to embedd YouTube Player in a Web View.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The YouTube API is used to add YouTube playback ability to your app, which means you will be able to embed a YouTube video within the interface of your app. Yes, it does need the official YouTube client to be installed, since that's what will be giving you the playback code, and the ability to play videos. But, you don't need to run it. The video will be within your app.

I haven't checked, but it's logical to assume that [`com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) is a View implemented in the YouTube official API, that will be injected in your app using the YouTube API, which will be rendering the video.

In order to render the video and play it in your app, you need support from the official YouTube app. Simple as that.

The [YouTube API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) does mention it will be available on devices running Android 2.2 (Froyo).

So in order to use the API, we must need support from the YouTube app.

Regarding your second question, please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5283856/1450401).

First of all, Google's YouTube app (4.2.16) that we use to support YouTube API is not open source. It is a free app but it doesn't mean it's open source. Google haven't published the source code of the latest YouTube app, and the YouTube API is also not open source. Moreover, it's an experimental project.

Have you seen the source code of these two projects anywhere?

Maybe they will come up with more modifications and features, but I think there is no workaround solution as you said.

If I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Thanks for quick response Edwin. I know I need support from the app as it is mentioned in the docs, but is there any workaround for this? I don't know if the Google's YouTube app is open source and maybe we can use its code to get this work??

Comment: The Youtube API client interacts with a service that is distributed as a part of the YouTube app for the Android platform..... This is a joke. I have developed almost the entire app because they don't specify that requires to have installed the youtube app into the device too.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go a new answer, this used iFrame inside a webview

[REFER](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player)

youtube api supports iFrame